# Bash Script: How to read a line from a file, that was passed as an argument, and store it in a variable

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, variables, arguments

I need to make a program that takes as arguments a number of files that contain lines like this: `num1:num2`.

I need to store the left column of numbers in one array and the right column and then do some things to them. I need some help on the first part.

The number of files passed as arguments is variable. Also I don't know the name of the files neither how many lines they have. I just know that I will get at least 1 file with 1 line.

I am trying to make a loop for each argument file and then read each file line, break down each line with some string manipulation and then store the results in the 2 arrays. However I haven't succeeded. I know that I also have other kinds of mistakes but I can fix those.

When I try to run the program using:

```
sh <my_program_name>.sh <argument1_filename>
```

I just get no results on the terminal, blank screen like it is calculating something in an endless loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

length=0
b=1
c=1
d=0
args=$#
j=0
temp=0
temp2=0
temp3=0
temp4=0

for temp in "$@"
do

while read line
do

stringtmp=line

tmp=`expr index "$stringtmp" :`
let tmp=tmp-1
stringtmp2='expr substr $stringtmp $1 $tmp'
lengh=`expr index "$stringtmp" \n`
let tmp=tmp+2
let lengh=lengh-1
stringtmp3='expr substr $stringtmp $tmp $lengh'
array1[$length]=stringtmp2
array2[$length]=stringtmp3

let length=length+1

done
...
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop is waiting for input from stdin. If you want to loop through contents of temp, you could use:

```
while read line; do
...
done<$temp
```

Comment: Did that already but i got the error "line 14: temp : no such file or directory" Line 14 is the first for-loop.

Comment: I can't believe I left it out, but temp should be $temp. Does that work?

Comment: @RataTara, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).